# gt 210 artifact when overclocked

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, overclocking

I tried to overclock my gt 210 with msi afterburner,
When i clicked apply random colored chess parts and green apeered on the screen and then it crashed
I have a 280W PSU
any way to overclock this thing?
I thing about replaceing it with a 1030

Comment: Overclocking a GT 210 is like putting 99 octane fuel in a Lada. Don't even bother.

Comment: welp its going to the trash anyways, i want to see what can it posibly do

Comment: It will go 1 mile an hour faster, so little difference you will never ever notice.

Comment: probably, but when it is going with 10mph 1 does make a minimal difference